# How can I check if an item is in a intermediate table and exclude it?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Order(models.Model):
    requester = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    taker = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models. EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)

class Picture(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name="pictures")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    show_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

I need to get all the pics that belong to certain event. Something like this:

```
Event 1:
Pic 1, Pic 2

Event 2:
Pic 3, Pic 4

Order 1:
Pic 1

Order 2:
Pic 3
```

What I need:

```
Event 1 has Pic 1 in an Order, so it can't be deleted
Event 2 has Pic 3 in an Order, so it can't be deleted

Pic 2 in Event 1 can be deleted
Pic 4 in Event 2 can be deleted
```

I want to know this because I'm using inline formsets, and I want to diplay the "Delete" checkbox only if the picture doesn't belong to an Order. In the example above, I want the "Delete" checkbox to appear only for Pic 2. I can achieve that with an `if` statement in the template, but I need the view logic.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a foreign key explicitly from Picture to Event, this should be as simple as `event.picture_set.all()`.

**Edit**

To exclude items that appear in an OrderItem, you would do:

```
event.pictures.filter(orderitem=None)
```

Comment: I't says that is an Attribute Error: 'Event' object has no attribute 'picture_set'.

Comment: EDIT:

If I try event.pictures.all() it brings me all the pictures associated to the event, but not if they are in the OrderItem intermediate table.

Comment: Then you can't be using the code you've posted above. `Event.pictures.all()` would only work if you had a related_name on the ForeignKey, which you don't.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I omitted it. Check the edit on the question.

Comment: OK. But now I don't understand what you mean by "not if they are in the OrderItem intermediate table". OrderItem can't possibly affect what you get back from `Event.pictures.all()`.

Comment: Because I don't need all the pictures, I only need the ones that are in the OrderItem model. In the example, only "Pic 1" but no "Pic 2".

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.